# What are the Nikon SB-910 speedlight’s overheating protection specs?

Tags: nikon, flash, hotshoe-flash

The Nikon SB-5000 speedlight is [rated](http://www.dpreview.com/news/6430959883/making-radio-waves-nikon-releases-sb-5000-speedlight) for 120 continuous shots at 5-second intervals without overheating. How does that compare to the SB-910 consecutive firing specifications?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually incredibly hard to tell you how that compares, since Nikon's never published that spec previously, and they don't tell you what power level the flash was on.  Most speedlights, set to a lower power setting could achieve those numbers very easily.

If, however, we assume full power without any loss of output, though, then that's impressive and should be an improvement.  The SB-910 could match the same firing pattern, but lowered the output of the flash when higher temperatures were reached vs. the SB-900 simply shutting down at around 50 full power pops.

See: [The Jordon Collective's Youtube video on their SB-900 vs. SB-910 overheating test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8li5VUc0ho).